# Why does the Multifield module not show an "Add" option?

Tags: entities

After downloading the [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module, I enabled it from the module section.

After that I went to `Structure -> Multifields`, to create a new Multifield. But there is no "Add" button, as shown in this image:

[image]

Any suggestions about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must add a Multifield field to a Content Type. For this go to:

```
admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/fields
```

[image]

And if you go to:

```
admin/structure/multifield
```

You will see your Multifield field and you will be able to "Add" (Manage subfields) the subfields

[image]

Comment: I am totally agree with your answer and thanks for it. later I tried that way and it is working. But why my question pop-up as I was referring Multifield Module tutorials where at two sources, it has shown that directly creating Multifield and Subfield from the Structure ->Multifield option itself. I am attaching link also just for reference    https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/managing-field-groups-in-drupal-with-the-multifield-module/